# PlantUML StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: class-diagram, plantuml

I've created a file (**test.puml**) with the following contents:

```
@startuml

!define Table(x) class x << (T,#FFAAAA) >>
!define primary_key(x) <b>x</b>
!define unique(x) <color:red>x</color>
!define not_null(x) <u>x</u>

hide methods
hide stereotypes

Table(user) {
    primary_key(id) BigAutoField
    not_null(password) CharField 128
    unique(not_null(email)) EmailField
}

@enduml
```

when building the UML diagram using the command below, everything works as expected.

```
java -jar plantuml.1.2019.5.jar test.puml
```

However, PlantUML versions 6, 7, 8 will return an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14
```

How can the above be achieved with the latest version of PlantUML?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it with the current development version:

> PlantUML version 1.2019.09beta21 (Unknown compile time)
>   (GPL source distribution) 
>   Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   Java Version: 1.7.0_67-b01

and here I don't get a problem and the image looks like:

[image]